# Why haven't newer dependently typed languages adopted SSReflect's approach?

Tags: coq, agda, idris, dependent-type, lean

There are two conventions I've found in Coq's SSReflect extension that seem particularly useful but which I haven't seen widely adopted in newer dependently-typed languages (Lean, Agda, Idris).

Firstly, where possible predicates are expressed as boolean-returning functions rather than inductively defined datatypes. This brings decidability by default, opens up more opportunities for proof by computation, and improves checking performance by avoiding the need for the proof engine to carry around large proof terms. The main disadvantage I see is the need to use reflection lemmas to manipulate these boolean predicates when proving.

Secondly, datatypes with invariants are defined as dependent records containing a simple datatype plus a proof of the invariant. For instance, fixed length sequences are defined in SSReflect like:

```
Structure tuple_of : Type := Tuple {tval :> seq T; _ : size tval == n}.
```

A `seq` and a proof of that sequence's length being a certain value. This is opposed to how e.g. Idris defines this type:

```
data Vect : (len : Nat) -> (elem : Type) -> Type
```

A dependently typed datastructure in which the invariant is part of its type. One advantage of SSReflect's approach is that it allows reuse, so that for instance many of the functions defined for `seq` and proofs about them can still be used with `tuple` (by operating on the underlying `seq`), whereas with Idris' approach functions like `reverse`, `append` and the like need to be rewritten for `Vect`. Lean actually has a SSReflect style equivalent in its standard library, `vector`, but it also has an Idris-style `array` which seems to have an optimised implementation in the runtime.

One [SSReflect-oriented book](http://ilyasergey.net/pnp/pnp.pdf) even claims the `Vect n A` style approach is an antipattern:

> A common anti-pattern in dependently-typed languages and Coq in particular is to encode such algebraic properties into the definitions of the datatypes and functions themselves (a canonical example
>   of such approach are length-indexed lists). While this approach looks appealing, as it demonstrates
>   the power of dependent types to capture certain properties of datatypes and functions on them, it
>   is inherently non-scalable, as there will be always another property of interest, which has not been
>   foreseen by a designer of the datatype/function, so it will have to be encoded as an external fact
>   anyway. This is why we advocate the approach, in which datatypes and functions are defined as close
>   to the way they would be defined by a programmer as possible, and all necessary properties of them
>   are proved separately.

My question is hence, why haven't these approaches been more widely adopted. Are there disadvantages I'm missing, or maybe their advantages are less significant in languages with better support for dependent pattern matching than Coq?

Answer (score 7):

I can provide some thoughts on the first point (defining predicates as boolean-returning functions).  My biggest issue with this approach is: then it is by definition impossible for the function to have bugs, even if it turns out what it's calculating isn't what you intended it to calculate.  In many cases, it would also obscure what you actually mean by the predicate if you have to include implementation details of the decision procedure for the predicate in its definition.

In mathematical applications, there will also be issues if you want to define a predicate which is a specialization of something which is not decidable in general, even if it happens to be decidable in your specific case.  One example of what I'm talking about here would be defining the group with a given presentation: in Coq, a common way to define this would be the setoid with underlying set being formal expressions in the generators, and the equality given by "word equivalence".  In general, this relation is not decidable, though in many specific cases it is.  However, if you are restricted to defining groups with presentations where the word problem is decidable, then you lose the ability to define the unifying concept which ties all the different examples together, and prove things generically about finite presentations or about finitely presented groups.  On the other hand, defining the word equivalence relation as an abstract `Prop` or equivalent is straightforward (if possibly a little long).

Personally, I prefer to give the most transparent possible definition of the predicate first, and then provide decision procedures where possible (functions returning values of type `{P} + {~P}` is my preference here, though the boolean-returning functions would work well too).  Coq's typeclass mechanism could provide a convenient way to register such decision procedures; for example:

```
Class Decision (P : Prop) : Set :=
decide : {P} + {~P}.
Arguments decide P [Decision].

Instance True_dec : Decision True := left _ I.
Instance and_dec (P Q : Prop) `{Decision P} `{Decision Q} :
  Decision (P /\ Q) := ...

(* Recap standard library definition of Forall *)
Inductive Forall {A : Type} (P : A->Prop) : list A -> Prop :=
| Forall_nil : Forall P nil
| Forall_cons : forall h t, P h -> Forall P t -> Forall P (cons h t).
(* Or, if you prefer:
Fixpoint Forall {A : Type} (P : A->Prop) (l : list A) : Prop :=
match l with
| nil => True
| cons h t => P h /\ Forall P t
end. *)

Program Fixpoint Forall_dec {A : Type} (P : A->Prop)
  `{forall x:A, Decision (P x)} (l : list A) :
  Decision (Forall P l) :=
  match l with
  | nil => left _ _
  | cons h t => if decide (P h) then
                  if Forall_dec P t then
                    left _ _
                  else
                    right _ _
                else
                  right _ _
  end.
(* resolve obligations here *)
Existing Instance Forall_dec.
```

Answer (score 7):

> This brings decidability by default, opens up more opportunities for proof by computation, and improves checking performance by avoiding the need for the proof engine to carry around large proof terms.

You don't have to carry around large terms as described in the [Edwin Brady's thesis](https://eb.host.cs.st-andrews.ac.uk/writings/thesis.pdf) under the name of "forcing optimisation". Agda does have forcing which affects type checking (especially how universes are computed is relevant), but I'm not sure if stuff used only at the type check time really gets erased before the run time. Anyway, Agda has two notions of irrelevance: `.(eq : p ≡ q)` is the usual irrelevance (meaning `eq` is irrelevant at the type checking time, so it's definitionally equal to any other term of such type) and `..(x : A)` is spine irrelevance (not sure if it's a correct term. I think Agda sources call such thing "non-strict irrelevance") which is literally for erasion of computationally irrelevant, but not completely irrelevant terms. So you can define

```
data Vec {α} (A : Set α) : ..(n : ℕ) -> Set α where
  [] : Vec A 0
  _∷_ : ∀ ..{n} -> A -> Vec A n -> Vec A (suc n)
```

and `n` will be erased before the run time. Or at least it seems to be designed so, it's hard to be sure, because Agda has lots of poorly documented features.

And you can write those zero-cost proofs in Coq, just because it too implements irrelevance for stuff that lives in `Prop`. But irrelevance is built-in into Coq's theory very deeply, while in Agda it's a separate feature, so it's perfectly understandable, why people find use of irrelevance in Coq more readily than in Agda.

> One advantage of SSReflect's approach is that it allows reuse, so that for instance many of the functions defined for `seq` and proofs about them can still be used with `tuple` (by operating on the underlying `seq`), whereas with Idris' approach functions like reverse, append and the like need to be rewritten for `Vect`.

It's not a real reuse if you have to prove properties anyway and those proofs have the same complexity as functions defined over indexed data. It's also inconvenient to do the job of a unification machinery and pass around explicit proofs and apply lemmas to get `length xs ≡ n` from `suc (length xs) ≡ n` (and also `sym`, `trans`, `subst` and all other lemmas that a unification machinery can save you from in many cases). Moreover, you lose some clarity by abusing propositional equality: having `xs : List A; length xs ≡ n + m` instead of `xs : Vec A (n + m)` doesn't improve readability of your contexts, especially if they are huge which is often the case. And there is another problem: sometimes it's just harder to define a function using SSReflect's approach: you mentioned `reverse` for `Vect`, I challenge you to define this function from scratch (with `reverse` for `List` as a "reused" part under the hood) and then compare your solution to the definition in `Data.Vec` from the Agda standard library. And if you don't have irrelevance enabled for propositions by default (which is the case for Agda), then you'd also need to prove properties about proofs if you want to prove, say, `reverse (reverse xs) ≡ xs` which is a lot of non-trivial boilerplate.

So SSReflect's approach is not perfect. The other one is too. Is there anything that improves upon both? Yes, Ornaments (see [Ornamental Algebras, Algebraic Ornaments](http://plv.mpi-sws.org/plerg/papers/mcbride-ornaments-2up.pdf) and [The essence of ornaments](https://pages.lip6.fr/Pierre-Evariste.Dagand/stuffs/journal-2013-catorn-jfp/paper.pdf)). You can easily get `Vec` from `List` by applying the corresponding ornamental algebra, but I can't say how much code reuse you'll get from it and whether types will drive you nuts or not. I heard people actually use ornaments somewhere.

So it's not that we have an ideal SSReflect's solution and others refuse to adopt it. There is just a hope for a more suitable way to get actual code reuse.

**UPDATE**

**Anton Trunov** in their comment made me realize I'm a bit too Agda-minded and people in Coq have tactics which can simplify proofs a lot, so proving in Coq is generally easier (provided you have weapons like `crush` from the [CPDT](http://adam.chlipala.net/cpdt/) book) than defining functions over data. Well, then I guess proof irrelevance by default and heavy tactics machinery is what makes SSReflect's approach effective in Coq.

Comment: Defining `reverse` function is easy: `Definition trev T n (t : n.-tuple T) := [tuple of rev t].`. Here we have reused `rev` function for lists (called `seq` in ssr-speak). Proving that `trev` is involutive is easy as well: `Lemma trevK T n : involutive (@trev T n).
Proof. by move=>t; apply: val_inj; rewrite /= revK. Qed.` Here we again reuse `revK` for lists and the non-trivial part proof-irrelevance lemma `val_inj`.

Comment: @AntonTrunov, interesting, thank you. Could you please elaborate how the proof works under the hood?

Comment: @AntonTrunov, oh, no, I mean a real reverse which appears to be named `rev'` in the Coq sources. Not the silly `| x :: l' => rev l' ++ [x]`.

Comment: I have used mathcomp's [linear time `rev`](https://github.com/math-comp/math-comp/blob/c17414bbef21bb3d0b96ee004c29ef7d56e55e2e/mathcomp/ssreflect/seq.v#L781).

Comment: The proof I provided above relies on `val_inj` lemma to strip off the `_ : size tval == n` part. In SSReflect `==` means boolean decidable equality and we operate on `nat`, so `val_inj` removes the proof-irrelevant part of `Tuple` and lets us deal with the underlying lists so we can reuse the list lemmas. Here is a [gist](https://gist.github.com/anton-trunov/1c82bdb3b77a3488b1cd909328631e05) with all the imports.

Comment: I just noticed your edit and I would say that SSReflect's approach to building proofs is an opposite to CPDT's one. Here we don't use any clever Ltac hacking (it's just `rewrite` and `apply`), but decidability certainly plays a major role.

Comment: @AntonTrunov, when I said "from scratch", I meant that you should prove the property over lists by yourself rather than take an existing proof. I checked the [sources](https://github.com/math-comp/math-comp/blob/master/mathcomp/ssreflect/seq.v#L817-L839), the existing proof goes from O(1) `cons` to O(n) `snoc` and back and it's far from being trivial. Tactics automate this a bit which is how clever tactics are related to the topic. [Here](https://github.com/agda/agda-stdlib/blob/cedbf87a91d28c56fd57baf99cae40f0bbcab649/src/Data/Vec.agda#L225) is how it looks in Agda.

Comment: But that would defeat the purpose of reuse :) And you mentioned this in your post: `(with reverse for List as a "reused" part under the hood")`. Btw, `reverse` for vectors in Agda looks really cool!

Comment: @AntonTrunov, can't express myself properly. I meant this situation: somebody defined functions over `List`s and wants to reuse them for `Vec`s the way SSReflect does it. He reuses `reverse` and now he is in trouble, because it's much easier to redefine `reverse` for `Vec` rathen than reuse `reverse` for `List`, because it is harder to prove the required property for `List`.